# jQuery animation disables form elements in Internet Explorer 7 and 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

We have a web application in production which uses jQuery for transmitting data via AJAX as well as for some of the basic animation methods (e.g. fadeIn, fadeOut, hide, show, slideUp, slideDown).

The framework of the software calls in dynamically loaded PHP files as panels on the main interface. After some extended use of our software, form elements such as text fields, text areas and select boxes become unclickable but only in Internet Explorer 7 & 8 (Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Internet Explorer 9/10 all work correctly). The form elements are definitely not disabled as our validation system never requires disabling the elements. We are also not using any layered HTML elements with z-index so nothing is potentially "hiding" or "transparent" over top of the elements that would interfere with an onclick event. There are also no scripting errors and the problem is so intermittent has been almost impossible to track down using break points.

We do not want to have to force our customers to use IE9+.

As best I can tell, this only occurs with form elements that have been transitioned in dynamically using jQuery with the animation effects. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: it is not allowed to offer money on stackoverflow for the correct answer (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=offer+money) so I removed your money offering. However if you provide a weblink I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: Somebody else had such problem http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?813625-Issue-with-jQuery-Selectbox-in-IE7

Comment: Does this post helps you?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354647/jquery-ui-buttons-some-issues-in-ie7
It seems a css problem.

Comment: Am I able to e-mail or private message you Daniele B? It would be great to set up a webinar where I can demonstrate the problem.

I'm still pretty new to StackOverflow... I haven't found a way to private message an individual for discussion.

Comment: Check my stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/users/1070844/daniele-b  profile for informations.